# How to display array with image details on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

How can I create an array ( I think ) which contains aditional information about an image and display it on thumbnail click? Thanks a lot for the help!

for example

```
thumbnail : 'link/x-thumb.jpg'
mainimg : 'link/x.jpg'
description : 'this is an image'
category : 'Abstract'
```

on x-thumb click, I want to display the information in a certain div. Also, how can I add a second detail area? Can someone help me or link me to a tutorial? Thank you very much!

Comment: from where do you get these details? please elaborate. :)

Comment: I'd like to write the details to display in my javascript file instead of writing endless code in HTML.  I want to add .click() function and toggle the details contained about that thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data has to come from somewhere. It can be stored in a javascript object, e.g. if your images have an id then you could use that as a key:

```
var imageData = {
  imageId0: {
    thumbnail : 'link/x-thumb.jpg',
    mainimg : 'link/x.jpg',
    description : 'this is an image',
    category : 'Abstract',

  imageId1: {
    thumbnail : 'link/y-thumb.jpg',
    mainimg : 'link/y.jpg',
    description : 'this is another image',
    category : 'Abstract',

  ...

  };
```

Then use a listener to format and display it. However, you are likely far better off to code it into an HTML element at the server, then use the listener to display it. Then you can key the id of the display element to the id of the image (e.g. 'image0-data'), your listener can be as simple as:

```
function showData(el) {
  showElement(el.id + '-data');
}
```

or similar, where the *showElement* function takes an ID and displays the element (there are many ways - transitions, modify class, modify display or visibility properties, etc.). Remember that the data must be sent regardless, so so you save nothing by sending it as script rather than HTML. You might save a bit on markup, but the server is much more efficient at generating that and it will be parsed by the client much faster if it's part of the original document.

Lastly, if you do it right, it gives you a great fallback. Non-scripted browsers can just display the data anyway, scriptable browsers can hide it then reveal on click.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! The problem I have is that the images load in the document without being toggled. It takes up much bandwitdth and results in massive loading times since it's a gallery, so I thought adding them throught javascript might save some work. Is there any way to make the image load only when the div containing it is shown?

Comment: @Grozav That's a tricky feature. If you have a vertical page (like facebook's feed), you can have many div's vertically and attach a scroll event to the document (or any containing div/iframe etc) and in that handler, you loop through all the div's that might have pictures in them and check whether their offset from top is bigger or smaller than the scrollTop+height attributes of the container. If so, you could load corresponding pictures or ignore if the div isn't  in view. If you have a more complex layout, figuring out whether pictures should be visible is more difficult.

Comment: I saw this website and took it as an example: http://www.julienpons.co.uk  if you click the thumbnails it loads the images afterwards. I tried reporducing this but failed.